# <Cosmicmind iOS> NaivgationDrawerController weird behaviour

Tags: ios, cosmicmind

I am trying to implement the Navigation Drawer Controller, I followed all the steps, but the controller is not working properly. When I swipe from the left edge to right, the left view is not presented as expected. Seems like the left view is showed as a right view controller.

Pod version: Material (2.4.9)

YouTube video: https://youtu.be/6NSNK3rJwZ8

Code: 
AppDelegate.swift

```
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {

        window = UIWindow(frame: Screen.bounds)
        window!.rootViewController = AppNavigationDrawerController(rootViewController: RootViewController(), leftViewController: LeftViewController(), rightViewController: nil)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

The `RootViewController` and `LeftViewController` are just copy and paste from the example project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks god, found the issue, so hard to trace this error.

the problem shown above is caused by `CEMKit-Swift` which is a framework provide some handy functions for fast prototyping, seems like there are conflicts between CEMKit-Swift and Material.

https://github.com/cemolcay/CEMKit-Swift

Comment: What are the conflicts? Interesting find.

Comment: sorry for late reply, `CEMKit-Swift` provides some handy `layout` functions, turnout messed up the `x` `y`(`x` turns to `y`, vice versa). Super weird, I comment out those part of code @ `CEMKit-Swift`, and turns out okay. Thanks for your great framework. Great work!